# Programmatically add layers to plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to add layers in plotly programmatically but can't seem to get around it's lazy evaluation.  Example:

```
p <- plot_ly()

for(kk in 1:5) {
  tmp <- cbind(rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15),rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15))
  p %<>% add_trace(x = tmp[,1], y = tmp[,2], type = "scatter", mode = "markers")  
}
```

In this example I was trying to plot a gaussian mixture model, however, the arguments to plotly aren't evaluated until they are viewed, so all five layers contain only the final value of tmp.  The command plotly_build is supposed force evaluation but I can't find examples of its usage and apparently I'm doing it wrong.

```
p <- plot_ly()

for(kk in 1:5) {
  tmp <- cbind(rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15),rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15))
  p %<>% add_trace(x = tmp[,1], y = tmp[,2], type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  plotly_build(p)     
}
```

Still gives the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it should be p <- p %>% add_trace......  because this answer does not work for me. %<>% throws an error, and without p <- in front of it, the layers are not stored, and thus not shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p <- plot_ly()

for(kk in 1:5) {
  tmp <- cbind(rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15),rnorm(1) + 0.05*rnorm(15))
  p %<>% add_trace(x = tmp[,1], y = tmp[,2], type = "scatter", mode = "markers", evaluate = TRUE)  
}
```

There is an evaluate argument to plotly.

Comment: looks like in the latest plotly (I'm on `plotly_4.5.2`), you don't even need the `evaluate = TRUE` statement so the very first example in your question works!